# What do difficulty levels do in Frogger 2: Swampy's Revenge?

Tags: frogger-2-swampys-revenge

The game options for Frogger 2: Swampy's Revenge on PS1 has difficulty settings for Easy, Normal, and Hard. What changes between difficulty levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to page 12 of the [Frogger 2 manual](https://oldgamesdownload.com/wp-content/uploads/Frogger_2_Swampys_Revenge_Manual_PS_EN.pdf):

> - Normal: The standard setting.
> - Easy: Start with more lives and with lots of extra lives to collect.
> - Hard: You must complete each level within a tough time limit.